# serverless artillery package not converting boolean to boolean values and null values to null

Tags: aws-lambda, load-testing, serverless, artillery

I am trying to use serverless artillery package for load testing AWS lambda functions(nodejs). I see two issues with this package. As the documentation claims, the boolean values in the input are not taken as boolean values, but are converted to string values. Also when input is null, it is converted to string value just in the case of boolean inputs. This is the link to their documentation -

https://www.npmjs.com/package/serverless-artillery#2-create-scriptyml

Am I missing something or are they bugs. When I gave the hardcoded input, I did not see any conversions to string for boolean and null values, but not in the case of inputs through csv file.